# loop a gridview and 2 lists to change one cell value, or use some other structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, for-loop, gridview

I have to programmatically change a value in a `GridView` cell, depending on whether a compatible value exists or not in a populated `List`. If the value does exist, then take the value from a second `List` and modify the `GridView` cell value.
The logic would be as follows:

> Check if the value of the list exists in the cell:

[image: Step1]

> Get the corresponding value from the second list and set it as the Gridview cell value:

[image: Step2]

The code I was trying to implement is as follows:

```
if ((originalCombo.Count > 0) && (destinationCombos.Count > 0))
{
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Rows.Count; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < originalCombo.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < destinationCombos.Count; j++)
            {
                if (GridView1.Rows[k].Cells[6].Text == originalCombo[i].ToString())
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[k].Cells[6].Text = destinationCombos[j].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have my entire logic wrong. Maybe I should use another method to iterate between the elements?

EDIT 1: So, probably I should be more clear about what I have and what I want to achieve. The `originalCombo` and `destinationCombos` are two lists, which are populated by a certain query. The `GridView` is already populated at the time I need to check for the value. So, if `originalCombo` and `destinationCombos` are not empty, I have to check the last cell on each row of the `GridView`, and if it's value is equal to one of the items of `originalCombo`,then I have to replace it with the respective value of `destinationCombos`

Comment: So you wanna update your gridview after it is already binded? where these list data is stored? In which event you are trying to do this?

Comment: @RahulSingh exactly. The lists and Gridview data are stored in the Database. The lists take values in base of several calculations, and I would like to add that value in a `ButtonClick` event.